# Deleting records in a table with billion records using spark or scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

we have a table in Azure Data Warehouse with 17 billion records. Now we have a scenario where we have to delete records from this table based on some where condition. We are writing Spark in Scala language in Azure Databricks notebooks.

We searched for different options to do this in Spark, but all suggested to first read the entire table, delete records from this and then overwrite the entire table in Data Warehosue. However this approach will not work in our case due to huge number of records in our table.

Can you please suggest how we can achieve this functionality using spark/scala?

1) checked if we can call stored procedure through spark/scala code in azure databricks but Spark do not support stored procedures.

2) Tried reading the entire table first to delete the records but it goes into never ending loop.

Comment: What's wrong with just running a simple SQL query `DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...` ? You can run SQL queries from Spark workers as well if you need.

Comment: we are using the azure databricks Scala notebook. if i used the delete query directly it gives the following output : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: A processing error "Parse error at line: 1, column: 31: Incorrect syntax near 'DELETE'." occurred. [ErrorCode = 0] [SQLState = null]  @simpadjo

Comment: Then you should just fix your SQL query. It's a separate problem.

Comment: You can just submit a query to sql dw rather than spinning up a databricks cluster, it is a bit like paying to fly first class around the world to go 5 doors down the road

Comment: In spark/hadoop, the database is a write once and then read only file. That means there are no direct commands available to delete and update. That was the reason people suggested to you that "first read the entire table, delete records from this and then overwrite the entire table in Data Warehosue"

Answer (score 0):

Is possible to create view  with select clause as per your requirement, then using of the view